# Error while reading CSV with VBA

Tags: vba, excel, csv

I'm trying to read a CSV with VBA. When following [this tutorial](http://www.homeandlearn.org/open_a_text_file_in_vba.html), I get the following code:

```
Sub OpenTextFile()

Dim FilePath As String
FilePath = "C:\path\to\file\mycsv.csv"
Open FilePath For Input As #1
row_number = 0

Do Until EOF(1)
    Line Input #1, LineFromFile
    LineItems = Split(LineFromLine, ",")

    ActiveCell.Offset(row_number, 0).Value = LineItems(2)
    ActiveCell.Offset(row_number, 1).Value = LineItems(1)
    ActiveCell.Offset(row_number, 2).Value = LineItems(0)

    row_number = row_number + 1
Loop

Close #1

End Sub
```

This is my CSV:

```
peter,paris,23
mary,london,34
steve,rome,56
lily,madrid,65
```

When executing the code, I get an error:

> Index out of range

And this line is marked yellow:

```
ActiveCell.Offset(row_number, 0).Value = LineItems(2)
```

Comment: what range does the `ActiveCell` relate to when this error happens?

Comment: @MacroMan: I'm new to VBA. The only information about the error I have, I already provided. That is the error message and the error line.

Comment: "I'm new to VBA" isn't really good enough, you can't google what `Range` and `ActiveCell` mean? If you don't put the effort into your question then people won't put the effort into answering it.

Comment: Everything seems to be correct. Yet, could it be that there is a `LineFromLine` with only one comma? Have you checked `LineFromLine`? Maybe add a `Debug.Print LineFromLine` and also add a break-point after the `split` to check `LineItems` for the item count: `Debug.Print UBound(LineItems) - LBound(LineItems) + 1`

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You have a typo:

```
LineItems = Split(LineFromLine, ",")
```

should be

```
LineItems = Split(LineFromFile, ",")
```

This would not have happened if you used `Option Explicit` at the beginning of your module ;)

Comment: If that really solves it then this is yet another good case to **always** include `Option Explicit` at the top of **each and every** module.

Comment: That really was a typo. Thank you.